# Vague error message: "Sorry, we cant accept this question"

Tags: support

I have received the an error message when trying to post the following question:

> If i update the rom on my nexus s to a
>   third party rom (like cyanogen for
>   example), is there anyway to restore
>   my nexus s to the original, default
>   android at a later date?

The error message read:

> Sorry, we cant accept this question

As you can appreciate, this is not a particularly useful error message. Does anyone know why my question could not be accepted, and how i go about proposing a more verbose error message?

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91464/problem-when-posting-new-question) and [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91072/150283) on the main Meta site for a bit of an explanation.

Comment: Make sure you pick a descriptive title, write an informative body, and provide relevant tags for your question. If it looks like you just typed out a question into the title and then pasted it into the body and tags, it'll probably be kicked back... And BTW: [search before you ask](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8333/how-to-flash-nexus-s-currently-on-custom-aosp-build-with-stock-gingerbread-by-g)

Answer (score 6):

I do not know the ins-and-outs of the automated quality filters that are in place. I suspect that the lack of capital letters might be one of the triggers. You don't mention the title you were trying to use; if it was identical to your question text that would be an easy filter to put into place.

You would do well to try some of the suggestions in the answers to the two questions eldarerathis linked to.